# How much do I charge?

Tags: pay-rate, price, negotiation, price-per-hour

I'm doing a freelance gig for a doughnut shop that has 3 locations and is about to open up a 4th making an android and iOS app. They want me to show all locations, have the app link to the nearest location based on your location, set up per-orders through square,  show the menu and other information about the business and offer coopons as well as a few more things. But this is my first freelance job for apps, and I'm not sure how much I should charge for this. Can anyone give me a quote?

Comment: Given that a mobile friendly website would be a lot better option than an app, I think you should not be charging them…….  Being a professional includes refusing to do work that is not of benefit to the client.

Comment: I already did a website for them and now they want me to do the app. I also explained that I don't think it would be if it them be he said he doesn't care, he wants an app. So I'm going with the customer is always right motto here.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1710/how-do-i-estimate-the-cost-of-building-an-mobile-app?rq=1

Comment: My dad told me that you should take the hourly rate that you make at a company and times it by 3. That way you are covered for the time that you aren't working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, charge by the hour. Without knowing a great many details about your expectations for payment, level of skill, customer expectations, graphics, whatever, it's impossible to come up with an accurate estimate that is going to make you happy.

Here's the deal though...you are in the same position. Fixed price gigs almost always (in my 30 years of freelance experience) have hidden expectations associated with them. When you charge a fixed price, you are essentially charging for a product that the client assumes will match what is in his or her head. You are estimating based on what is in your head and most of the time you end up spending more time with fussy details or surprise requirements that you aren't being paid for but essentially agreed to do when you took on the project.

At some point, you will have to have the conversation with the client where you both decide when you are done, or where to draw the line between work that is part of the fixed price estimate and work that is over and above. Those aren't usually fun meetings.

If you charge by the hour, then it really doesn't matter as much...the client can keep generating requests and you keep building. They'll stop generating requests when development reaches their budget limit. Be sure to negotiate a regular invoicing and payment schedule while you are at it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be instances where the client may need an hourly based contract or a fixed-price one. I would suggest going by the hourly method.

In order to quote for the project, you need to make the timeline sheet on your side first. Include all the features and modules and list down the number of hours it will take you to get them done.
Be sure to include buffer time in it as well. Otherwise, it will come back and bite you later, if you get any of the modules delayed. It is a safe practice to have buffer time.

After you do this, share the doc/sheet with the client and get their approval. Make sure they checked the whole doc and made sure nothing was missing or was extra.

Once that is done, you are good to go.You have the estimated timeframe in front of you and you have to do whatever it takes to stick to it and give the best quality delivery possible.